# How to create on-board USB blaster for Intel FPGAs?

Tags: intel-fpga

Intel/Altera FPGA development boards only require a USB cable to configure the FPGAs. There is no need to buy a byte blaster. How is the USB blaster implemented on these boards, is this method/design open to public?

Comment: which of the hundreds of different boards are you referring to? And: have you tried reading datasheets? It's not like the serial programming or JTAG interfaces are undocumented.

Comment: The vendor publishes documentation covering your choices.  You must not attempt to design an FPGA board without carefully reading a lot of such documentation, for many reasons beyond just this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice example of a low cost USB blaster equivalent circuit that was based around a PIC18F14K50, and about $5 of components. Details of the original project can be found [here](http://sa89a.net/mp.cgi/ele/ub.htm) (Note: site is in Japanese).

I've used the design a couple of times quite successfully. The design and firmware I used (based on the original from the aforementioned link) can be found in this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/TCWORLD/6fa3ab7cf97a63db882845c53dd6e195).

Answer (score 0):

JTAG is standardized, and you can create [Serial Vector Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Vector_Format) programming files from the toolchain that can be interpreted to give the correct programming sequence for the IC regardless of what is driving the JTAG lines.

Typically people would use one of the FTDI USB-to-serial converter ICs for that. The USB Blaster is also just an USB to serial converter, I'm not sure which IC they use, but it's reasonably common that you can buy USB Blaster clones cheaply.

Comment: Is USB Blaster II the same type of device?

Comment: @Quantum0xE7, the USB Blaster uses a CPLD for a slightly more efficient transfer than would be possible with pure USB-to-serial converters, but that is an implementation detail. OpenOCD supports the [USB Blaster I and II](http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/html/usb__blaster_8c_source.html).

Comment: I see, is it possible to achieve data rates higher than the Intel provided USB blaster II using 3rd party hardware? The Byte Blaster II is rather expensive device for what it does.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7, yes, although with rising data rates, complexity rises as well. The simple FTDI based solutions are slow, because the JTAG state machine is implemented on the host, so every time data needs to be read back (such as status flags), we need to wait for all the USB transfers to finish. That's why the USB Blaster has a CPLD -- it implements the state machine, so we only need to transfer a stream of commands that can include conditionals like "repeatedly query the status, and continue when the "done" flag goes high."

Comment: @Quantum0xE7, they justify the price with the debugging capabilities -- in Quartus, you can mark a signal that you want to monitor, and it generates FPGA code to write a copy of the signal into a FIFO, and make it available via JTAG. The protocol for that isn't public, and complex enough that you need the CPLD to implement it efficiently (because there is lots of waiting for data).

Comment: @Quantum0xE7, for pure programming, there is a good chance that just increasing the clock rate will work -- the default 10 MHz is a conservative setting, because JTAG links are usually not that great from a signal quality point of view. With the full connector that has a GND line between signal lines, and appropriate routing on the board, 50 MHz should be unproblematic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to integrate the USB Blaster onto your custom board.  The design is not in the public domain AFAIK.  You should just use the JTAG header, and buy a Terasic USB Blaster, which is exactly the same as the Altera/Intel USB Blaster but 1/4 the cost.